# Issue with hamburger icon menu without javascript

Tags: html, css, menu, icons

I got some issue with the hamburger icon menu, it doesn't show on mobile devices. Probably because of the ':has' in css
Can someone create an alternative to open the menu for mobile devices ?
this is the code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  background-color:#909090;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  display: none;
}

header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.logo-text{
  color:#FFF;
}

.hamburger-icon{
  border:none;
  background-color:transparent;
}

.hamburger-icon .fa-bars,
.hamburger-icon .fa-x{
  color:white;
  font-size:1rem;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.hamburger-icon input[type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.navigation a{
  color:white
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  header {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .hamburger-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .fa-x{
    display:none;
  }
  header:has(.hamburger-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked) .navigation {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    height:100px;
  }
  header:has(.hamburger-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked) .fa-bars {
    display:none;
  }
  header:has(.hamburger-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked) .fa-x {
    display:inline-block;
  }
}


/* Content CSS */
.container{
  height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
}

.container p{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:3rem;
  color:#FFF;
  text-shadow:2px 2px black;
  transition:all 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1 class="logo-text">LOGO</h1>
    <button class="hamburger-icon">
      <label for="dropdown">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars">OPEN</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-x">CLOSE</i>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dropdown" />
    </button>
  </div>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="container">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
</main>
```

I would appreciate it if someone could fix an alternative to open the menu for mobile devices. Only using html and css

Thanks!

Comment: https://codepen.io/streetsz/pen/OJdjNGv

Comment: I see your code works well. However there are 2 issues:
- Your hamburger icon is empty because you didn't embed font icon.
- You need to set your hamburger icon with color:white to see it.

Comment: @KaZaT ok thanks I get it now.. the code i tried is this: 
      <label for="dropdown">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars">Open</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-x">Close</i>